# How to change to cd rom drive in terminal Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, guest-additions

How do you switch to the directory where the CD-ROM is?  I am at

```
name@name-virtualbox:-S
```

Comment: for guest additions (you tagged it) see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox

Answer (score 5):

The CD-ROM is usually mounted in `/media/<user-name>/<disc-name>`  You can get there in terminal by typing:

```
cd /media/<user-name>/<disc-name>
```

or through Nautilus by selecting the disc on the left side.